# Ag grid to check if column is visible or not

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid

I'm trying to hide/Show columns in Ag grid.

Below is my code for hiding/showing columns

```
 this.gridOptions.columnApi.setColumnsVisible(["Col1", "Col2"], true);

 this.gridOptions.columnApi.setColumnsVisible(["Col3", "Col4"], false);
```

How do i find, if the columns are already hidden or visible ? based on the current state of the columns, i need to execute the above code. Please help

Comment: columnApi.getColumnState()?

Comment: No with columnState, it return hide: true/False, But i need visible:true/false

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
this.gridOptions.columnApi.getColumn("Col1").visible
```

[Source](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-api/):

> **getColumn(colKey):** Returns the column with the given 'key'. The key can either be the colId (a string) or the colDef (an object).

Comment: 'visible' is private in Column so this may give a warning. A substitute is: this.gridOptions.columnApi.getColumn("Col1").isVisible()

Comment: bonus question: how do you get all visible columns?

Comment: @parliament - Use the grid's column API (like above) and call getAllDisplayedColumns()